# Google Maps tile lineup issue

Tags: google-maps, alignment, tiles

I am currently working on a website and I want to display quite a small google map with the size of 200px x 200px but for some reason I am getting multiple issues with this.

[Image of the Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWhYW.jpg)

As you can see in the Image, there is a grey line on the left side, the tiles do not match up and the position of the marker isnt right either.

Does anybody know why this is happening? I read around a bit but all I could find was only people having issues with grey lines but not with the tile misalignment mixture.

I currently have setup up a html file with the map div, like this:

```
<div id="map_30" style="height:200px; width:200px; float:left;"></div>
```

Does anybody have any clue why this is happening?

Thank you!

EDIT: I have added a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/acs90m6k/

Comment: Please post a fiddle so we can see the issue

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.  [The "code" you posted so far does not](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/o85nx8x0/) (but it is probably a CSS issue)

Answer (score 1):

try adding

```
  <div id="map_30" style="height:200px; width:200px; 
           float:left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;"></div>
```

I have tried this and work fine (a small 200x200 map in the top left of the page)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Info windows</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map_30" style="height:200px; width:200px; float:left; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;"></div>
    <script>
      function initialize() {

          //Map parametrs
          var mapOptions_place = {
              zoom: 6,
              center: new google.maps.LatLng(-16.39, -71.83),
              mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

              mapTypeControl: false,
              mapTypeControlOptions: {
                  style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
                  position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER
              },
              panControl: false,
              panControlOptions: {
                  position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
              },
              zoomControl: false,
              zoomControlOptions: {
                  style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.LARGE,
                  position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT
              },
              scaleControl: false,
              scaleControlOptions: {
                  position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
              },
              streetViewControl: false,
              streetViewControlOptions: {
                  position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP
              },
              scrollwheel: false
          }

          //map
          var map_place = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_30"), mapOptions_place);

          var quake_3 = 'img/map-icons/quake-3.png';
          var quake_4 = 'img/map-icons/quake-4.png';
          var quake_5 = 'img/map-icons/quake-5.png';
          var quake_6 = 'img/map-icons/quake-6.png';
          var quake_7 = 'img/map-icons/quake-7.png';
          var quake_8 = 'img/map-icons/quake-8.png';

          //positions
          var point_place = new google.maps.LatLng(-16.39, -71.83);

          //markers
          var marker_place = className = 'Test';
          var marker_place = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: point_place,
              map: map_place,
              category: quake_3,
              title: "point_place"
          });
      };

      //google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initialize"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That didnt change anything sadly. Here is a Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/acs90m6k/

Comment: Then it must be some issue regarding the css of the containers of my map. Thanks for verifying that for me. I will keep on trying.

Comment: If my answer is useful please rate it